# Laravel: how to get the start and end record number of current page?

Tags: laravel

I have a line like this:

```
$users = User::where(something)->paginate(20);
```

> On page 1, the start number is 1, end number is 20
>   On page 2, the start number is 21, end number is 40

If now I'm on page 2, how to get numbers 21 and 40?

Comment: You shoud go through this. [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#converting-results-to-json)

'from' and 'to' can help u get ur need

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#converting-results-to-json
You can see the response has a from and to in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `->firstItem()` and `->lastItem()` method to get limit of pagination, [Check for more details](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html)

```
$users = User::where(something)->paginate(20);
$from = $users->firstItem();//will give you 20(index of 21st item) on page 2
$to = $users->lastItem();//will give you 39(index of 40th item) on page 2
```